# How do I delete my Christianity.SE account and make my email private?

Tags: support, status-completed, user-accounts

Could somebody help me delete this? It is showing my email, and I do not want my email public.

Comment: Your email is only showing to you. We can't see it.

Comment: Instructions for deleting your account can be found [here](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/deleting-account).

Answer (score 6):

I think both points were addressed in comments, but to make it official:

- Your email is not public, it only shows on your profile when *you* view it. Other users cannot see that field.
- If you still want to initiate deletion of your account there are [instructions in the help center](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/deleting-account).